# Convert spark dataframe into json files which contains array of json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am writing Spark Application in scala which reads the HiveTable and save the output in HDFS as Json Format file.

I read the hive table using HiveContext and it returns the DataFrame. Below is the code snippet.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkReadHive")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df = sqlContext.sql(
      """
        |SELECT *
        |FROM database.table
        |""".stripMargin)

df.write.format("json").save(path)
```

I need output file looks like below:

```
[{"name":"tom", "age": 8},
{"name":"Jerry", "age": 7}]
```

However, what I get is like below:

```
{"name":"tom", "age": 8}
{"name":"Jerry", "age": 7}
```

Can someone please help me with it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **`.toJSON, collect() and .mkString`** method to get array of json objects and by using hadoop filesystem to create a file in hdfs with the desired format.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._ 
import java.io._

//sample dataframe
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(("tom",8),("Jerry",7))).toDF("name","age")

//making array of json object
val data=df.toJSON.collect().mkString("[",",\n","]")

//filesystem object
val path = new Path("hdfs://<namenode>:8020/<path>/myfile.txt")
val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val fs = path.getFileSystem(conf)
if (fs.exists(path))
    fs.delete(path, true)
val out = new BufferedOutputStream(fs.create(path))
out.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"))
out.flush()
out.close()
fs.close()
```

---

**`Check contents of file in HDFS:`**

```
hadoop fs -cat myfile.txt
[{"name":"tom","age":8},
{"name":"Jerry","age":7}]
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! However, it ends up all the items in the array in a single line. Is there any way we can do some change in the code to make it per item per line, like what  I described originally.